# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'day' error when trying to put day and times into arrays

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

Im trying to open csv files then pull the days into the days array and the times into the times array but i get this error "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'day'". I have added an image to what one of the files looks like

```
data = {'days': [],
        'times': []}

with open(open_file) as in_f:
    reader = DictReader(in_f)
    for line in reader:
        data['day'].append(line['time_received_isoformat'].day)
        data['time'].append(line['time_received_isoformat'].hour * 60 + line['time_received_isoformat'].minute)
        data = DataFrame(data)
        plot = seaborn.stripplot(data=data, x='day', y='time')
        plot.get_figure().savefig('/home/jacob/Projects/CIS2302/CW2/ddd_cw2/temporal_graphs/' + 'days_stripplot' + '.png')
        pyplot.close()
```

Comment: line['time_received_isoformat'] seems to return a string an not a dictionnay. Try to print(line['time_received_isoformat']) to see what it gives you

Comment: Ino, but i dont know what to do to solve it...

Answer (score 0):

`in_f` is a file object, `reader` is a `DictReader` object with that file, and `line` is a dictionary of strings. `line['time_received_isoformat']`, therefore, resolves to a string, since CSV files contain strings. Strings do not have a `day` attribute. If you want them to be parsed as `date` or `datetime` objects, which do have a `day` attribute, you will need to parse that string into such an object (which will vary depending on the exact format you have) before trying to find its `day`.

Comment: @JacobFlynn What does `time_received_isoformat` look like? There are several valid ISO formats for timestamps.

Comment: I can't see the content of your CSV file, so I can't tell you exactly how that field should be parsed. You will need to tell your program what kind of string to expect and what to do with it.

Comment: `time_received_isoformat
2015-06-01T00:00:00
2015-06-01T00:00:12` I just copied this from the file @TigerhawkT3

Comment: @JacobFlynn: You can read about time parsing in the python standard library `time` module: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/time.html#time.strptime